# ignoring multiple line comments in java

Tags: java, regex, reluctant-quantifiers

I am writing a program where I need to ignore comments in the file passed.
I read about Regex pattern in this concern..and am able to ignore single line comments(//...) and multiple line comments, if its defined in a single line (/*...*/).
But am facing difficulty in ignoring multiple line comments like shown below:

>

/* ........
..........
....*/

for single line I used

> "//.*$"

and for the second one,

> "/\ \ * . * \ \ * /"

Somewhere I even read that Reluctanat quantifier would be helpful...tried with differnt patterns using regex and reluctant quantifier...no joy..
Can someone help me with this..?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it will works for you :

```
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

or for both single line and multiline comment :

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.` normally does not match new line characters like `\r`, `\n` and others.
You can however use DOT_ALL which changes this behaviour. This is identical with the `(?s)`.

```
"(?s)/\\*.*\\*/"
"/\\*[.\r\n]*\\*/"
```

This replacement should be done before treating single line comments. And there `.` should not match a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the suggestions..However,I got one exact solution... the pattern 
"(?s)/\*.+?\*/" works fine in removing multiline comments..

Comment: Please use backticks to `\`format code like this\``.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following to solve your problem
      "(?s)/\*.*\*/"
      "/\*[.\r\n]*\*/"